# Use InputType Number but format edittext live text to phone number format

Tags: android, android-edittext, phone-number

So the easiest way for the edittext to format your input is to use the phone inputType. The problem is that this gives you a few other symbols other then numbers. And I don't want the user to be able to type in those symbols.

- I tried to only listen to digits by doing android:digits by this causes the input to no longer be formatted.

Is there a trick that i could do to get this to work? Other then writing a custom textWatcher that formats the text.

Comment: can you specify what is phone number format?

Comment: Use input type number

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show only numbers in your keyboard just like this screenshot [image]

You have to use `numberPassword` input type instead of `phone` input type

```
  android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

But when you apply this your entries in `editText` appear as bullets because `inputType` is `numberPassword`, So to solve this problem make a new java class for example:

```
public class NumberKeyPadTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
    return source;
}}
```

And in your `main activity` where you fetch the ids of `edittext` or where you use that `edittext` you have to simply add one line of code

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(new NumberKeyPadTransformationMethod());
```

Your whole problem will solve.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use as Athira pointed:

```
  android:inputType="number"
```

and if you want decimal numbers then:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```